# Display the same Android fragment twice and use call getById

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

So I have 2 fragments visible if the user uses a device with a big enough screen `(like a Samsung Galaxy Tab)`.

Right now I am displaying a fragment list twice `(same fragment twice)`. Inside the code of the fragment I use this to hide a progressbar.

```
ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.progress);
pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Problem is that it only works on one of the fragments. Both have the same id since its the same fragment?
Should I create 2 identical fragments or is it possible to find the "correct" progress-bar in the correct fragment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In stead of finding the view (the `ProgressBar`) in the activity's view hierarchy, find it in the fragment's view hierarchy. So inside the fragment, do the following:

```
ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar) getView().findViewById(R.id.progress);
```

Generally, you don't want to do lookups in the parent's view hierarchy, so above basically applies to all views in the fragment's layout.

Comment: Did not know about the getView() method to return just the current view. Worked like a charm, thanks.